# Is there a way to stop prettier / prettier-now from breaking function arguments into new lines

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, format, prettier

When using prettier / prettier-now to format on save, when a function wraps around another function it breaks to a new line, I was wondering if there was a to stop this behavior?

For example:

Desired output:

```
app.get('/campgrounds/:id', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render('campgrounds/show', { campground });
}));
```

Prettier / Prettier-now output:

```
app.get(
    '/campgrounds/:id',
    catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
        const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
        res.render('campgrounds/show', { campground });
    })
);
```

Comment: I'd recommend starting here for some prettier configuration options: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

Comment: You can Ignore this block of code using  
// prettier-ignore https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Answer (score 2):

You can tell prettier to stop formatting a block of code by using
Comment // prettier-ignore

For example:

```
A(
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
)

// prettier-ignore
B(
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
)
will be transformed to:

A(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    
// prettier-ignore
B(
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1
)
```