# Prettier/VSCode breaking the syntax

Tags: prettier, prettier-eslint

I am trying to format a js file with [prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier) but it seems prettier is breaking the code syntax. I want to achieve this
([expectated result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMDVe.png)) but the red lines appear. On save I get the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X8s4.png). While running the code I get the following error `TypeError: {} is not a function` ([error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l9Rr.png)). I tried the following but none seems to work in my case.

1. [Why do I keep getting Delete 'cr' [prettier/prettier]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier)
2. [Visual Studio Code [eslint] Delete 'CR' [prettier/prettier] on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750853/visual-studio-code-eslint-delete-cr-prettier-prettier-on-windows)

I am using the following .prettierrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  tabWidth: 2,
  bracketSpacing: true,
  endOfLine: "auto",
  jsxBracketSameLine: true,
  printWidth: 100,
  semi: false,
  singleQuote: false,
  trailingComma: "none"
}
```

In my .eslintrc.json file I have the following rules set for prettier

```
"prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "bracketSpacing": true,
        "endOfLine": "auto",
        "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
        "printWidth": 100,
        "semi": false,
        "singleQuote": false,
        "trailingComma": "none"
      }
    ],
```

I have tried changing LF to CRLF and vice versa that appears in the bottom section of vscode but no success. What else am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66149802/is-there-a-way-to-stop-prettier-prettier-now-from-breaking-function-arguments/66182235#66182235

Comment: Thanks. This works but it's a workaround and not a good practice in my opinion.

Comment: Still, the error persists.

Comment: prettier follows all good practices and format the code accordinglly however sometimes users want different formating style in that case we have to ignour some block of  codes